# How to invoke "{Model.Foo} updated" after model update?

Tags: javascript, javascriptmvc

I have a javascriptMVC Model

```
/**
 * @class Hzfrontend.Models.Warmwasser
 * @parent index
 * @inherits jQuery.Model
 * Wraps backend warmwasser services.  
 */
$.Model('Hzfrontend.Models.Warmwasser',
/* @Static */
{
    findAll: "/api/warmwasser",
    findOne : "/api/warmwasser/{id}",
    update : "/api/warmwasser/{id}"
},
/* @Prototype */
{
    update : function(attrs, success, error){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url:"/api/warmwasser/"+this.id,
            data: $.toJSON(this), 
            success: success,
            error: error,
            dataType: "json"});
    }
});
```

and a Controller:

```
$.Controller('Hzfrontend.Warmwasser.List',
/** @Static */
{
    defaults : {}
},
/** @Prototype */
{
    init : function(){
        this.element.append(this.view('init',Hzfrontend.Models.Warmwasser.findAll()) )
    },
    '.waterTemperature change': function( el ){
            var mod = el.closest('.warmwasser').model();
            mod.attr('waterTemperature', el.val());
            mod.update();
            steal.dev.log("update waterTemperature");
    },
    "{Hzfrontend.Models.Warmwasser} updated" : function(Warmwasser, ev, warmwasser){
        warmwasser.elements(this.element)
              .html(this.view('warmwasser', warmwasser) );
        steal.dev.log("updated");
    }
});
```

after the update completed I want to invoke the updated callback in the controller. How to do this?
If I use the ./fixtures/fixtures.js' to test the app without a server backend, it works without any problems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That code should work. What do you return as a response from your server? You should return an JSON response with the object that you updated.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a prototype update method.

Comment: ok, but how to send the request as json without "$.toJSON(this)" in the prototype?